# Developing under Spring Framework, how to get the current URL inside a form response?

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

This is a REST application using Spring Framework.

Look, in some point of the payment process, I request the form to redirect to the payment URL:

```
    @RequestMapping( value="/{id}/online-payment", produces="text/html", method={ RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET } )
    @ResponseBody
    public String onlinePaymentForm( HttpServletResponse response,
            @PathVariable( value="id" )String eventId,
            @RequestParam( value="temporalDataId", required=true )String temporalDataId,
            @RequestParam( value="amount", required=true )Double amount
            ) throws Exception
    {   
...
else if( conn.getGateway() == PaymentGateway.PAYPAL)
            {
                return paypalPaymentsServices.buildPaymentForm(
                        conn, temporalDataId, amount, event.getName(), data.representantParticipant() );
            }
...
}
```

When the application gets the form, auto submit the obtained form (`onload=submitForm()`). What I want to do is to put the current URL or the current domain name in the response form, for example:

I know how to do it using `HttpServletRequest request` with `request.getRequestURL()`, but as you can see this method is receiving an `HttpServletResponse response`.

Maybe exists is a class with static methods or a way to get the current URL using Spring Framework or Java?

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you tag this PHP?

Comment: If you know how to do it with `HttpServletRequest`, why don't you just add an `HttpServletRequest request` parameter to the method?

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, can you explain if I add that `HttpServletRequest` parameter, how will change the way to invoke this method?, in other words, what I need to change with this new parameter?

Comment: @StephenC I don´t do it, Stackoverflow offer it, I simply click all offers.

Comment: Oh Duh!  Why did you do that?  The assumption is that you will use your common sense and only select tags that are *relevant to the question*.  You do understand the purpose of tags, don't you?

Comment: @DesarrolloDesafiodeGuerrero Spring is calling your method. Add the parameter and Spring will provide the value. The Spring documentation shows what kind of values are available: [Web MVC framework - Defining RequestMapping handler methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods)

Answer (score 1):

If you add a request parameter, then you should be able to use it; e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}/online-payment", produces="text/html",
                method={RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
@ResponseBody
public String onlinePaymentForm( 
        HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        @PathVariable(value="id") String eventId,
        @RequestParam(value="temporalDataId", required=true) String id,
        @RequestParam(value="amount", required=true) Double amount
        ) {   
    ...
}
```

The mapping infrastructure recognizes and binds a `HttpServletRequest` parameter if you are within a `Servlet` based container.

Comment: @Stephen_C I changed and it affect the URL resolution in the browser, I get a 404 not found ... what I is necessary to change to take this parameter work fine? ... You said: mapping infrastructure recognizes and binds.. that infrastructure is mine or is from spring?